# Hyphenation of "second most northerly"

Tags: adjectives, american-english, hyphenation

I've changed my mind a number of times about which of these variants works best:

1. > the **second most northerly** coffee shop in Seattle
2. > the **second-most-northerly** coffee shop in Seattle
3. > the **second-most northerly** coffee shop in Seattle
4. > the **second most-northerly** coffee shop in Seattle

I've tried to do a little research, but I'm not even sure what to call something like this, so I haven't had much luck.

Any guidance on what is considered most clear/correct would be much appreciated!

Comment: Which coffee ship is under discusison?

Comment: _secondmost_ is already a word. You don't need a hyphen between an adverb and its modified adjective.

Comment: @KarlG: People use the spelling "secondmost", but I haven't found it so far in any of the major dictionaries, and one of the contributors to the Wiktionary talk page had misgivings about this spelling: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:secondmost

Comment: @sumelic: I think you're right. How about _second nothernmost_ then?

Comment: I was typing that as well. Actually, I was typing the "the secondly northermost" ;)

Comment: "Second-least southernmost"

Comment: @KarlG That rather sounds like there are two northernmost coffee shops, of which this is the second one. I’d probably just cop out altogether and say _second-northerliest_ (even if it is a bit unwieldy to inflect three-syllable adjectives).

Comment: Maybe *northernmost-but-one*.

Comment: Number 2 - "second-most-northerly..." - would be my choice, and, I suspect, the most favoured in a humanities department of British university.  I'm not sure what "style guide" that adheres to, if any.

Comment: 'Hindmost' is a familiar word - meaning the farthest to the rear.  'Most' in hindmost modifies 'hind'.  'Secondmost' is new to me. If I have understood the usage correctly 'most' in 'secondmost' modifies a following adjective (unspecified).  This seems odd and unhelpfully confusing.

Comment: *Chicago Manual of Style* has a free 10-page pdf [Hyphenation Table](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/images/ch07_tab01.pdf), which is highly recommended and ought to be considered a general reference since it's free and freely available. However, whether it includes this exact combination is as yet unknown to me. The biggest rule for hyphens is don't use them unless you need to prevent ambiguity. Is there ambiguity in 'second most northerly coffee shop"?

Comment: @Knotell - I agree.  Perhaps, when reading the sentence for the first time, it would help the reader to make clear that most-northerly is compound adjective?

Comment: @ArmthegoodguysinAmerica it looks like it is not free anymore

Answer (score 9):

I'd be inclined to write this as "the second most northerly coffee shop in Seattle", with no hyphens. But hyphenation is far from a definite area of English punctuation. I don't think any of the options that you list is unclear or ambiguous in practice.

## Google Ngram Viewer data

While I'm not entirely sure of the accuracy of the [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+second+most+common%2Cthe+second-most+common%2Cthe+second-most-common%2C+the+second+most-common&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20second%20most%20common%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20second%20-%20most%20common%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20second%20most%20-%20common%3B%2Cc0) with hyphenated phrases, it seems to suggest that "the second most common" is much more frequent than "the second-most common":

[image]

(The double-hyphenated spelling "the second-most-common" was so infrequent that it did not show up at all on the Ngram Viewer chart.)

## CMOS rules that seem applicable

The Chicago Manual of Style (17th ed) gives somewhat complicated rules for hyphenating phrases like this.

### It recommends using a hyphen between a ordinal number and a superlative

In the original version of this answer, I missed the fact that there is actually a special section in the CMOS hyphenation table for "number, ordinal, + superlative". This says to use a hyphen after words like "second" when they come before an attributive superlative adjective. The examples are

> a *second-best* decision
>   
>  *third-largest* town
>   
> *fourth-to-last* contestant
>   
>  he arrived *fourth to last*

Unfortunately, none of these examples show how to hyphenate a phrase that uses *most* rather than *-est* to form a superlative adjective. The example of *fourth-to-last* shows hyphenation between all words in the phrase, not just after the word *fourth.*

The CMOS's recommendation here seems a bit unusual to me, actually. A number of dictionaries mention this use of *second* and give examples without hyphenation:

- OED *second, adj. and n.<sup>2</sup>* 2b : "With following superlative: Having only one superior in the specified attribute."

  > 1979   *Nature* 15 Feb. 561/2   *Secernosaurus* is the second most primitive hadrosaur known.

  (the OED entry does give one example quotation that uses hyphenation, "1977   *Word* **28** 104   The second-youngest of the fluent speakers.")
- [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/second) *<sup>3</sup>second* adverb 2 : "before all others with one exception · the nation's *second* largest city · They are my *second* favorite band."
- [AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=second) 
  *second<sup>2</sup>* adv. 2 : "But for one other; save one: the *second highest peak*."

So I don't think it's universally regarded as unacceptable to use a space rather than a hyphen after *second* in this context. The preference for a hyphen between *second* and an immediately following attributive superlative adjective seems to be something that is particular to the *Chicago Manual of Style* (I'm not sure what other style guides say about this topic).

### But CMOS also recommends not using a hyphen with *most,* or with an adverb that is modified by another adverb

CMOS 17 says

> certain compounds, including those with *more, most, less, least,* and *very,* can usually be left open unless ambiguity threatens.

For example, it recommends writing "the *most efficient* method" without a hyphen.

What it means by "unless ambiguity threatens" is indicated with the following pair of examples:

> the *most skilled workers* (most in number) but
>   
> the *most-skilled* workers (most in skill)

So my interpretation is that, according to CMOS 17, it might be acceptable to write something like "the most-northerly coffee shops" to avoid the alleged ambiguity of "the most northerly coffee shops" (e.g. a sentence like "This street has the most northerly coffee shops in Seattle" is theoretically ambiguous, although not really in practice because "northerly" isn't an adjective that typically can apply to a bunch of different shops).

I can't find support in CMOS for using a hyphen before but not after *most.* It says

> When the adverb rather than the compound as a whole is modified by another adverb, the entire expression is open.

The relevant pair of examples is "a *much-needed* addition" vs. "a *very much needed* addition". (It's a bit unfortunate that this uses the adverb *very*). Based on this, it seems to me that if *second* is viewed as an adverb modifying *most,* then you should write the whole thing with spaces according to CMOS.

Now, it's not clear to me that this is the actual function of *second* in this phrase.  The [AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=second) does have an entry for *second* as an adverb, but the OED does not, and lists this use of *second* under the entry for the adjective. 
The fact that we can say things like "the second highest mountain", where the equivalent of the word *most* is expressed by a suffix *-est* on the adjective, suggests to me that *second* in this context is not used as a modifier of the adverb *most* (since that adverb is not even present in "the second highest mountain"). On the other hand, I guess some people can say things like "the most and second most important reason", which might indicate that "second most" is treated as a phrase (I'm not sure).

## Two hyphens: recommended by "Daily Writing Tips"

Although the use of two hyphens seems to be uncommon, as I mentioned in the Google Ngram Viewer section, it has been recommended by at least one person. The Daily Writing Tips article "[5 Examples of Insufficient Hyphenation](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/5-examples-of-insufficient-hyphenation/)", by Mark Nichol, criticizes the punctuation of “The adviser some call the world’s second-most powerful man prefers to work behind the scenes,” saying

> *Second-most* is a nonsensical modification of “powerful man.” *Powerful* is part of the ranking, so it should be part of the phrasal adjective: “The adviser some call the world’s second-most-powerful man prefers to work behind the scenes.”

Comment: I wouldn't trust Ngrams at all for this. It can't distinguish line end hyphens, nor phrases such as *first- and second-most*, which are two other reasons to deploy hyphens. Also, I think the results from the nonhyphenated search  include every variety of hyphenated phrasing.

Comment: @PhilSweet: I don' t think the line for the nonhyphenated Ngram term includes hyphenated examples. A Google Books search would work that way, but book search works differently from the Ngram Viewer. Compare ["the well known" vs. "the well-known"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+well+known%2C+the+well-known&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20well%20known%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20well%20-%20known%3B%2Cc0), where the hyphenated form is more frequent

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's the apostrophe in contractions that can't be distinguished from non-contracted forms. Hyphens work fine.

Comment: I’m inclined to think that second does modify most. If we take your example of second highest mountain does it make sense to test by shortening? We can shorten to second highest and to second mountain. The first maintains more of the sense than the second. [Second highest] mountain would mean the second highest, whereas second [highest mountain] is a. non-sensical because you can’t have multiple highest mountains and b. ambiguous because it could refer to the second according to a different order than height. It seems the second [highest mountain] could be highest, for ex. from the west

Comment: @Unrelated: I'm saying that I think the structures are "the (second [highest]) mountain" and "the (second [most northerly]) coffee shop". I don't think "second" modifies "coffee shop", but I think it modifies "most northerly" rather than just modifying the word "most" by itself.

Comment: Funny how you can have *foremost* but not *secondmost*. You can also have *easternmost, innermost, leftmost*, even *lattermost* rather than *last*. There’s a tug-of-war between using *-st* superlatives and *-most* superlatives. OED mentions that the restriction of applying *-most* only to words denoting position in place, time, or serial order has existed since Old English and persists to our own day except in nonce-words.

Comment: @tchrist: "the second-northernmost coffee shop" could be used (and it seems CMOS 17 would call for a hyphen here), but I didn't read the question as asking for alternative word choices. Apparently, "foremost" is not actually originally from "fore" + "most". I think "secondmost" seems odd semantically to me: what would it mean for something to be "the most second"? There aren't degrees of second-ness, are there?

Comment: I don't know what Ngrams has to do with this at all. When people ask about hyphens they usually want style guide rules not frequency of usage, favoring prescriptive over descriptive. Since your answer still puts the Ngram in prominent position I can't remove my dv.

Comment: @Knotell: The Google Ngram Viewer looks at frequency of usage in published, edited works. Past a certain point, it doesn't make sense to say that nearly all publishers or all educated writers are mistaken in their punctuation practices. Even prescriptivists recognize that language norms are established by usage, not just by fiat.

Comment: Google Books contains a plethora of works not published by reputable publishers, and it is to style guides that educated writers turn, especially in regard to hyphenation.

Comment: @Knotell: If I found clear guidance in a style guide about how to punctuate "the second most northerly coffee shop", I would put that in a section above the Google Ngram Viewer data. The CMOS section is currently placed lower down because I didn't find any clear examples of how to hyphenate this exact kind of phrase.

Comment: There is a difference between *the second most common* used as a NP and *the second most common* used before a noun; does your Ngram show that?

Answer (score 6):

A hyphen should be used to force the parsing "(second most) northerly" rather than "second (most northerly)". Thus, it should be "second-most northerly".

Comment: The question asked which option should be chosen. I said which option should be chosen, and explained why. That seems like an answer to me.

Comment: Is this phrase actually parsed as "(second most) northerly"? Consider that we can say things like "the second highest mountain", where the equivalent of the word "most" is expressed by a suffix *-est* on the adjective. This makes me think that the correct parsing is "(second [highest])" and "(second [most northerly])".

Comment: What is the difference between *(second most) northerly* and *second (most northerly)*? When looking at a map of US states, for example, would one be Minnesota (state with northernmost point in US, other than Alaska) and the other North Dakota (state with northernmost southern border, other than Alaska)? If so, which would be which? Or maybe *second (most northerly)* would be Washington, as it's the most northerly state after Alaska when reading from left to right?

Comment: @1006a That is the exact trouble here. Hyphenation, however you do it, does not succeed in removing any ambiguity. For example, between second chronologically and most geographically, compared to second most geographically. And nothing will get me to parse it (second most), what ever that means. What is required is suitable context that enables a us to understand in what sense it is second.

Comment: @Acccumulation My comment concerns the lack of research, which makes it an opinion based answer unsupported by examples, style guides, or other reference material. If you add support along the lines of sumelic's answer, I'll delete the comments, but I think you will have a hard time doing that.

Comment: I would love a citation because whilst I fundamentally understand when to use hyphens I am never able to explain the logic to anyone, and most people seem to struggle with at lease some examples.

Comment: -1 answer not supported by any reference or usage

Answer (score 2):

Surely the primary variable here is the 'northerliness' of the coffee shops' locations.  Consider the following:

> '***The Coffee Cup***' is a coffee shop in Seattle.
>
> '***The Barista Bar***' is another coffee shop in Seattle.
>   It is further North than '*The Coffee Cup*'.
>
> '***Luscious Lattes***' is another coffee shop in Seattle.
>   It is further North than '*The Barista Bar*'.

The simplest way to make clear their relative northerliness is to say:

> *Luscious Lattes* is the most northerly coffee shop in Seattle.
>
> *The Barista Bar* is the second most-northerly coffee shop in Seattle.
>
> *The Coffee Cup* is the third most-northerly coffee shop in Seattle.
>
> *etc*.