# How to use multiple hyphens

Tags: hyphenation

Which is the correct way to hyphenate the following message: **the hotel in question is, among all the hotels in Dehli with the same 4-star rating, second best.**

> This is the second-highest-rated 4-star hotel in Dehli.

or

> This is the second-highest rated 4-star hotel in Dehli.

or something else?

Comment: *Of the four-star hotels in Delhi, this one has the second-highest average guest rating.*

Comment: Similar: [Hyphenation of “second most northerly”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/459536)

Comment: 'The hotel in question is rated as the second best 4-star hotel in Delhi'

Comment: This doesn't sound too bad in speech, where you compartmentalise [secondhighestrated] and [4star]. The way to do this if transcribing is to use hyphens as in your first example. But if you're not transcribing speech verbatim, go with Jason's or Littletee's rewrite. There's a useful quasi-rule somewhere about avoiding unwieldy stacked modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt is correct. The second is wrong. Let me begin with the second sentence. To me, "This is the second-highest rated 4-star hotel in Dehli" says something about how tall the building is. That is, among all 4-star hotels that have been given a formal rating, this hotel is the second-highest. In contrast, your first sentence correctly explains that it is the rating that is the second highest.

Having considered correctness, I think that it is then worth considering how best to say what you want to say, and in that case, the construction suggested by @Jason is easy to understand and unambiguous.