# "second largest" vs "second-largest"

Tags: hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

Does this construct require an hyphen?

Example:

"We obtained the dataset from HP, the second largest firm in the US by revenues."

"We obtained the dataset from HP, the second-largest firm in the US by revenues."

Comment: Hello, robertspierre. Does this answer your question? [Hyphenation of "second most northerly"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/459536/hyphenation-of-second-most-northerly) 'In the original version of this answer, I missed the fact that there is actually a special section in the CMOS hyphenation table for "number, ordinal, + superlative". This says to use a hyphen after words like "second" when they come before an attributive superlative adjective. The examples are ...........
_• a second-best decision
• third-largest town_ ...': @herisson

Comment: Also, in your sentence, "revenue" would be expected. https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/revenue.html#:~:text=The%20noun%20revenue%20can%20be,Find%20more%20words!

Comment: ... and why the close votes? This is very specific to be be considered gen ref.

Comment: @Phil Sweet The CMOS section mentioned in the claimed duplicate (whose title question is a slight variation) actually gives • _third-largest town_ as one of its recommendations. I assume it favours clarity (one presumes 'third largest house' would be the third of the set of identical largest houses under consideration) over prettiness.